# What is a best IDE for oracle?

Tags: oracle, ide, sqlplus, oracle8

I Work on a ORACLE 8.0.I know how to run oracle SQL command's in SQLPLUS.
I searched to find a IDE such as SQL Server Management Studio but couldn't find it. 

 what is best IDE for ORACLE?
thanks

Comment: not sure about Oracle 8, but look into Oracle SQL Developer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Comment: [dbForge Studio for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/features.html) is a powerful Oracle IDE that aimed to increase PL/SQL coding speed, provides versatile data editing tools for managing in-database and external data, etc.

Answer (score 6):

"Best" is a matter of opinion - available environments include:

- [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)
- [Toad for Oracle](http://toadfororacle.com/index.jspa?product=toadfororacle)
- [Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html)

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  Oracle 8.0 has been obsolete for almost 15 years.  That's an ancient version of the database.  Are you sure you're really using something that old?  That definitely complicates things because it means that any vaguely recent version of the Oracle client won't be able to connect to the database so you're eliminating the vast majority of tools.

If you're really stuck with an ancient version of Oracle, the old Java based Enterprise Manager application that shipped as a part of the Oracle client is the closest thing to SQL Server Management Studio.  I don't know if that was available way back in Oracle 8.0 but the version that shipped with the 8.1.7 Oracle client should connect to an Oracle 8.0 database.  Of course, Oracle no longer makes either the 8.0 or 8.1.7 Oracle client available for download and you'd need to have a pretty old version of the operating system to be able to install something that old.  If you still have a support agreement (though that seems unlikely since you haven't upgraded Oracle in my working lifetime) you might be able to open a support request and get Oracle to send you a CD for desupported versions of the database or client.

Comment: _(though that seems likely since you haven't upgraded Oracle in my working lifetime)_ Did you mean "unlikely"?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - Yup.  D'oh.  Thanks for the catch-- edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I know that this version of oracle is too old. 
I found oracle 8 in old CD  and install it  XP WINDOWS>Vbox and run it :) 
be happy

Comment: @Mehran - You know that you can download the current version of Oracle for free from the Oracle web site to use to teach yourself Oracle, right?  If you do that, you'll end up with a ton more options for tools plus you'll get the web-based Enterprise Manager Database Control and SQL Developer thrown in.

Comment: Justin- so gooooooooooood i will download it as soon as possible. thank you very much